# Удаление строк из dataSet C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Возникла проблема связанная с удалением строк из `dataSet`, связанного с *.mdf базой. Связь между ними была создана автоматически в Visual Studio. В базе есть две таблицы, связанные между собой ключом. При удалении родительской таблицы все проходит нормально, но при удалении дочерней таблицы командой:

`database1DataSet.Products.Rows[currRow2].Delete();`

выдается ошибка:

> Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row.

По советам в SO добавил строку:

`database1DataSet.AcceptChanges();`

Но теперь другая ошибка:

> This row has been removed from a table and does not have any data.
>   BeginEdit() will allow creation of new data in this row.

Выдается она при выполнении следующего кода:

```
public string Производитель {
            get {
                return ((string)(this[this.tableProducts.ПроизводительColumn]));
            }
            set {
                this[this.tableProducts.ПроизводительColumn] = value;
            }
        }
```

В классе

`public partial class ProductsRow : global::System.Data.DataRow`

дизайнера dataSet.

Советов по ее решению почти нет, поэтому решил написать сюда. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Думаю тебе нужно что-то типа транзакций. Т.е. пока ты все хвосты не подчистишь, изменения в БД не применятся окончательно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сообщения об ошибках довольно ясно дают понять, что идёт обращение к удалённой строке.

Пример кода, как это может возникнуть:

```
// Сохранили существующую строку в переменную
DataRow row = dataTable.Rows[0];

// Удалили эту строку из DataTable
// Но ссылка на неё сохранена в row
dataTable.Rows[0].Delete();

// Обратились к удалённой строке
// Здесь будет ошибка
string temp = row[0].ToString();
```

Ищите в своём коде, где вы пытаетесь работать с уже удалёнными строками.

Comment: @ahgpoug - Вероятно, есть привязка данных к контролам. Где-то в них держится ссылка на удаляемую строку. Не видя весь код, ничего больше сказать не могу.

Comment: Обновил данные в посте.